# помогите пожалуйста после проверки, webbrowser.open("https://google.com/search?q="+com) выполняется бексонечное количество раз что делать?

Tags: python, pyttsx3

```
while True:
    # старт записи речи с последующим выводом распознанной речи
    # и удалением записанного в микрофон аудио
    voice_input = record_and_recognize_audio()
    os.remove("microphone-results.wav")
    print(voice_input)

    com = voice_input
    com[com.find("найди в google" and "найди в гугле")+2:]



    # отделение комманд от дополнительной информации (аргументов)
    voice_input = voice_input.split(" ")
    command = voice_input[0]
    #разговорнные штуки
   
    
    #функции
    if "google" or "гугле" in voice_input: 
        webbrowser.open("https://google.com/search?q="+com)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: *выполняется бексонечное количество раз что делать?* — убрать `while True`